# How can I copy a stack by using a temporary stack?

Tags: copy, stack

This is my code as a beginner, I wanted to implement the idea that shown in the picture.
Is there any better way to improve it?

> ````
> ```
> Stack originalStack=new Stack();
> Stack TempStack=new Stack();
> Stack copiedStack=new Stack();
>
> orginalStack.push(1);
> orginalStack.push(2);
> orginalStack.push(3);
> orginalStack.push(9);
> int StackLength=orginalStack.size();
>   
> for(int i=0;i<StackLength-1;i++)
> TempStack.push(originalStack.pop());
>
>
> copiedStack.push(originalStack.peek());
>  
> do
> {
> copiedStack.push(TempStack.peek());
> originalStack.push(TempStack.peek());
> TempStack.pop();
> }while(TempStack.size()!=0);
>
>  System.out.println("Stack 1 "+originalStack);
>  System.out.println("Stack temp "+TempStack);
>  System.out.println("Stack 2 "+copiedStack);
> ```][1]
> ````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this is a good way to copy a stack. Nice solution! I do think you have a small bug by iterating in your `for` loop to `i < StackLength - 1` though: It should be `i < StackLength` because as written you're not going to get to the last element of originalStack nor push it onto TempStack, so it won't show up in the copied stack. You could code more defensively around this type of off-by-one error by just looping until `originalStack.size() == 0` like you do in your `do-while` loop.

Style-wise you could improve the code by including more spaces (it seems like everything within any given line is crunched together as close as possible, which isn't generally as readable as it could be), and you should probably camel case `tempStack` and `stackLength` to be consistent (you usually reserve names with initial letters capitalized for classes). You could even wrap your code for copying a stack into a function.

This is a separate issue, but with Java, you should try using parameterized types, like `Stack<Integer>` or `Stack<T>`/`Stack<E>` (stack of any type/any elements) so the compiler can check you code for type safety and help avoid run-time errors. It's kind of verbose, but that's just how Java is. Plain, un-parameterized collections ("raw types") are more of a legacy feature that are best avoided. If that's just something you haven't gotten to yet though, don't worry about it, you will soon.

So here is how I would spruce things up

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class CopyStack {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> originalStack = new Stack<>();
    originalStack.push(1);
    originalStack.push(2);
    originalStack.push(3);
    originalStack.push(9);

    Stack<Integer> copiedStack = copyStack(originalStack);

    System.out.println("Stack 1 " + originalStack);
    System.out.println("Stack 2 " + copiedStack);
  }

  public static <T> Stack<T> copyStack(Stack<T> originalStack) {
    Stack<T> tempStack = new Stack<>();
    Stack<T> copiedStack = new Stack<>();

    while (originalStack.size() != 0) tempStack.push(originalStack.pop());

    do {
      copiedStack.push(tempStack.peek());
      originalStack.push(tempStack.peek());
      tempStack.pop();
    } while (tempStack.size() != 0);

    return copiedStack;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, no problem! Also, I just realized that in the version with the function the do-while loop should probably just be a while loop, so you wouldn't get an error in case you tried to copy an empty stack (peeking an empty stack throws an exception).